# Using iterator for removing items from map in c++

Tags: c++11, dictionary, iterator

```
map<int, int> m_map;
// ...
map::iterator it =  m_map.begin();
while (it != m_map.end())
{
  m_map.erase(it++);
}
```

When does the `++` action take place? Is it before or after the `erase`? When would it be safe to do so?

Comment: that depends on implemention. its better to use [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom](erase-remove idiom)

Comment: @BruceAdi Erase-remove only works for sequence containers, not for associative ones.

Comment: Surely its better just to call `clear()` on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's specified whether the `++` happens before or after the call to `erase`. Still, even if it was guaranteed to be peformed before the call, the fact that you had to asks shows that the code is bad. There is a better, 100% safe alternative:

```
while (it != m_map.end())
{
  it = m_map.erase(it);
}
```

[`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) returns an iterator to the element past the erased one.

Comment: I'd go further. Even if the `++` happens after the call (which is I think it does), it will still be undefined behaviour. It is meaningless to increment an iterator which points at an item which has already been erased. My rule of them is that I should never ignore the return value from a call to `erase` as the return value is probably the only well-defined thing I have access to!

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I believe the two operations (increment and call) are indeterminately sequenced; if the increment happens first, it's OK, if the call happens first, it's UB as you say. But your words regarding the return value of `erase` are very wise.